# probability - applying chain rule (maybe)

Tags: probability

I have the following problem:

> The probability of an animal being a cat is 30%.
>
> The probability that an animal cat weighs more than 3 kg is 60%.
>
> Given an animal is not a cat, the probability of it weighing less than or equal to 3 kg is 60%.
>
> What is the probability of an animal being a cat if it weighs more than 3 kg?

In my head I translate this to:
A = being a cat,
B = being an animal,
C = weighting more than 3 kg.

So that:

$P(A|B) = 0.6$

$P(C|A, B) = 0.7$

$P(\bar C|\bar A, B) = 0.7$

$P(A, B | C) = ?$

I am pretty clueless on how to solve a such problem...

Applying the chain rule I get anywhere close to something looking like a solution.

Already, is my formulation correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First exclude $B$ as it's always true. Then draw a table like $$\begin{array}{r|cc}
& Cat& \overline{Cat}\\ \hline
W>3&x&y\\
W\le3&z&t\\
\end{array}.$$
It's given that $$\begin{cases}x+y+z+t=1\\ x+z=3/10\\ x/(x+z)=3/5\\ t/(t+y)=3/5\end{cases}$$
[$$\begin{cases}
t = 21/50\\ x = 9/50\\ y = 7/25\\ z = 3/25
\end{cases}
$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2By%2Bz%2Bt%3D1%2C+x%2Bz%3D3%2F10%2C+x%2F%28x%2Bz%29%3D3%2F5%2C+t%2F%28t%2By%29%3D3%2F5)
We're asked about $x/(x+y)=9/(9+14)=9/23$.

P.S. I *do not* assume "Cat" and "$W\gtrless 3$" to be independent. Such table is the only intuition available to me for problems like conditional probability.